# Python 3 AttributeError even though attribute exists

Tags: python, replace, attributes, find, attributeerror

I have a set of python files which make up a program for saving tidbits of info and searching them via tag association. I had the program working for many versions, but I recently made what I thought was a minor change that caused the program to go haywire. The ENTRY object is the basis of the data storage - it holds a unique ID number, a nickname, a value, and a list of tags.

```
class ENTRY:

def __init__(self, idNum, nickName, value, tagList):
    self.idNum = idNum
    self.nickName = nickName
    self.value = value
    self.tagList = tagList
```

I realized that I was interchangeably referring to the "nickName" attribute as "name" when asking for input in other files, so I decided to Find and Replace all mentions of "nickName" with "name" to make the code easier to follow.  I did this in the ENTRY.py file as well as all of the associated python files in the program.  I even proofread them to make sure the change did not mess with any case-sensitive function calls or anything.

The problem: Now, when I run the program, I get an attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Memory/TagMem.py", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Memory/TagMem.py", line 207, in main
    dispatch(userChoice)
  File "/Memory/TagMem.py", line 171, in dispatch
    nameList('todo')
  File "/Memory/TagMem.py", line 103, in nameList
    memory.searchListNames(queryList)
  File "/Memory/Memory.py", line 96, in searchListNames
    each.printName()
  File "/Memory/ENTRY.py", line 49, in printName
    print("({}) {}".format(self.idNum, self.name))
AttributeError: 'ENTRY' object has no attribute 'name'
```

But after the Find and Replace, the ENTRY object most certainly has an attribute 'name':

```
class ENTRY:

def __init__(self, idNum, name, value, tagList):
    self.idNum = idNum
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
    self.tagList = tagList
```

Does anyone know of a reason I would get an attribute error when the attribute is very clearly defined in the class constructor?

For more complete information on the full class code, see the github repository: https://github.com/kylelambert101/TagMem

And the specific commit with the crash-inducing changes:
https://github.com/kylelambert101/TagMem/commit/68987f2e6ed98012f36ec5230b3dac6f09373489

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you're running the version you think you are.

Comment: It looks like you're importing a user-written class from one file into another file that you're executing, right?  If that's the case, did you try exiting the Python interpreter and starting it back up?  Changes to your dependent modules don't get updated when you re-run unless you've exited.

Comment: Hmmm, I have exited and reopened the program a couple of times, so I don't think that's the problem. However, your comment made me think about which files are trying to access ENTRY.name, and I think the problem is that I pickled the database with a bunch of old ENTRY objects inside. I can make new entries just fine, but when I try to access the name attribute of old ones, I get the error. I will try fixing it and update my post if that's the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out where I went wrong! My program is associated with a file called `myMemory.dat` which stores a pickled version of a `Memory` object and is loaded and saved with each run of the program. The `Memory` object is essentially a list of `ENTRY`s to be queried. At the time when I updated all of my code to use the name `name` instead of `nickname`, I already had hundreds of `ENTRY` objects saved in `myMemory.dat` - each an instance of the old `ENTRY` object with a `nickName` attribute instead of a `name` attribute. When I called functions which attempted to access the `ENTRY` object's `name` attribute, the program threw an error because the `ENTRY` objects in question did not have that attribute.

The fix: I looped through the `Memory` object stored in `myMemory.dat` and copied all of the info into new `ENTRY`s in a new `Memory` object. I saved the new `Memory` to `myMemory.dat`, and the program works good as new!

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of attribute definition in the class's `__init__()` method. Imagine you have a class `Foo` with the private attribute `_bar`. Further imagine that the class `Foo` has a method `foo_bar()` that manipulates the attribute `_bar`. If you call the `foo_bar()` method in the `__init__()` method before defining the `_bar` attribute, you will get an `AttributeError`.

**Example in Python:**

```py
class Foo:
    _bar: str

    def __init__(self):
        # Uncomment the next line to fix the issue
        # self._bar = "success"

        self.foo_bar()  # Calling foo_bar() before defining _bar will result in an AttributeError

        # Comment the next line to fix the issue
        self._bar = "error"

    def foo_bar(self):
        print(self._bar)


obj = Foo()
```

In this example, if you uncomment the line `self._bar = "success"` and comment the `self._bar = "error"` one, the code will run without errors. However, if you leave it as is, you'll get an `AttributeError` because the method `foo_bar()` is called before the attribute `self._bar` is defined in the class.