# getattr returns a default even though attribute exists in dict keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a file containing some json which I load and loop through the "servers" items and pass them to a `send_alert()` method (items marked "REDACTED" are not the real code/output):

```
"servers": [
  {
    "address": "smtp.gmail.com", 
    "encrypted-password": "Copy and Paste from 'password' after encryption.", 
    "login-name": false, 
    "port": 587, 
    "type": "email"
  }, 
  {
    "address": "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 
    "encrypted-password": "<REDACTED>", 
    "login-name": "<REDACTED>@yahoo.com", 
    "port": 587, 
    "type": "email"
  }]
```

I expect the gmail item to be skipped because it should render False or None for the 'login-name'... so I am really just processing the yahoo item:

```
def send_alert(self, server, message, email):
    print(json.dumps(server, encoding=self.encoding,
                                 sort_keys=True, indent=2))
    print(type(server))
    print(server["login-name"])
    username = getattr(server, "login-name", None)
    enc_pass = getattr(server, "encrypted-password", None)
    address = getattr(server, "password", None)
    port = getattr(server, "port", None)
    server_type = getattr(server, "type", None)
    mess = message
    if not username:
        print(username)
        self.log.warn("incorrectly configured alert!\n:%s",
                      json.dumps(server, encoding=self.encoding,
                                 sort_keys=True, indent=2))
        return False
    if server_type.lower() == "email":
        self.send_email(username, enc_pass, address, port, mess, email)
    else:
        self.log.debug("unknown server type listed in Alerts/servers")
```

when `send_alert` is called, I receive the following output:

```
{
  "address": "smtp.mail.yahoo.com",
  "encrypted-password": <REDACTED>,
  "login-name": "<REDACTED>@yahoo.com",
  "port": 587,
  "type": "email"
}
<type 'dict'>
<REDACTED>@yahoo.com
None
[11:35:39] [Wrapper.py/WARNING]: incorrectly configured alert!
:{
  "address": "smtp.mail.yahoo.com",
  "encrypted-password": <REDACTED>,
  "login-name": "<REDACTED>@yahoo.com",
  "port": 587,
  "type": "email"
}
```

I would like to use getattr, versus testing (`if "login-name" in server:`) or try-excepting the values.  I have done this in other cases with success.  However, this has me stumped.  `getattr()` is returning the default value of None, even though a valid key item seems to exist.  What is wrong?

I tried some of the suggested "Questions that may already have your answer
" and none have given me any help.  This one seemed promising but was either never answered or the answer (provided by the asker) does not apply to my case: [Python 3 AttributeError even though attribute exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018475/python-3-attributeerror-even-though-attribute-exists)  (i.e., I tried to deepcopy the single dictionary item server before passing it to send_alert)

The output is the same for both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Why?, the Json.dumps part works just fine..

Comment: The item server is already a dictionary.  The json.dumps readout is only for debug or error messages...

Comment: `getattr` gets the attributes of an object, not the elements in a container.  You're not asking for `server['login-name']` but `server.login-name`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you Patrick!

Comment: It's already a dictionary, stack.  Read the real answer from Patrick Haugh

Comment: use `server.get('login-name', None)` instead

Comment: create an answer Pat, and I will accept it.

Comment: yea I saw, I thought you were passing json directly, my bad @SurestTexas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) gets the attributes of an object, not the value associated with a key in a mapping.

`getattr(server, 'login-name', None)` is trying to access the attribute `server.login-name`, not the value `server['login-name']`

You can instead use the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method

```
server.get('login-name', None)
```